# No matching constructor found on type in a Windows Phone 8.1 Resource Dictionary

Tags: xaml, constructor, windows-phone, windows-8.1, resourcedictionary

All of a sudden all my definitions in the resource dictionary had an error and the studio underlines almost my entire code inside the dict. It tells me that "The text associated with this error code could not be found" and then "No matching constructor found on type". How to fix this and where exactly is the problem. Since its too much code to publish and i suppose it's something trivial I made a screenshot:

[image: http://s14.postimg.org/g1vj541rk/Untitled.jpg]

Comment: In your project's **Build** section (in project properties), try setting the Platform Target to `x86`. It might be that it needs to be set to `Any CPU`, I can't remember which one. Try both anyway.

Comment: No, its not this. I tried it

Answer (score 1):

What VS version are you using ? Visual Studio 2015 RC XAML Designer is still has some little bugs.Did you clean your solution & rebuild or tried to restart Visual Studio ?

Comment: I am using VS 2015 RC yes